# Initializing 2D Array in A Class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I am trying to initialize `nums` 2D array in a Class `Construct`. I am using the default constructor to initialize it but since it has already been created I am unable to. I cannot initialize it in the class either. I have tried initializing each element manually and it works but I want to just initialize `nums` in one line.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

class Construct { 
public: 
    int nums[3][3]; 

    // Default Constructor 
    construct() 
    { 
        int nums[3][3] = {{4,5,42,34,5,23,3,5,2}}
    } 
}; 

int main() 
{ 

    Construct c; 
    cout << "a: " << c.nums[1][0] << endl 
        << "b: " << c.nums[0][1]; 
    return 1; 
}
```

I have tried
`nums[1][0] = 5` ... but that is not very efficient. Any feedback would be great.

Comment: You're just declaring a local variable which happens to be of the same name as the member variable, and which will be gone as soon as you're out of the function. BTW, you need to use the exact class name in order for this function to serve as a constructor. BTW 2, the dimensions of `{{4,5,42,34,5,23,3,5,2}}` are **not** 3 x 3.

Comment: Use a member initializer list for the constructor. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use initializer list

```
Construct(): nums {{4,5,42},{34,5,23},{3,5,2}}
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to be able to inititalize your class with custom values, you will need to provide a constructor that takes some kind of a container as an argument and uses it to initialize your array: `i.e. Construct(const atd::array<int, 6>&)`.

But to avoid the overhead of rewriting all the values of an already initialized array, you will need to use a Pack expansion.

Here is a customized class template that provides such a constructor:

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

// typename of an underlying array, sz0 and sz1 - array dimensions
template <typename T, size_t sz0, size_t sz1,
    class = decltype(std::make_index_sequence<sz0 + sz1>())>
    class Construct_;

// expanding a Pack of indexes to access std::array's variables
template <typename T, size_t sz0, size_t sz1,
    size_t ... indx>
    class Construct_<T, sz0, sz1, 
        std::index_sequence<indx...>>
{
// make it private or use a struct instead of a class
    T nums_[sz0][sz1];

public:

    // nums_ is initialized with arr's values. No additional copies were made
    Construct_(const std::array<T, sz0 + sz1> &arr)
        : nums_{ arr[indx] ... }
    {}

};

using Construct33int = Construct_<int, 3, 3>;

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 6> arr{ 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };
    Construct33int c{ arr };

}
```